# Setup nagivation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to implement navigation controller to look like in the screenshots below in UIKit?

By default

[image: 1. by default]

When user scrolls

[image: 2. when user scrolls down]

Generalizing, I need to have large title, small label above large title and button with image

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = "Subtitle"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I tried that, but that does not look in the way I've shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

you can create your header that you want on as a swift file and .XIB file like:

```
import Foundation
import MarqueeLabel
import GSKStretchyHeaderView
import UIKit

@objc
public class **YourHeaderFileName**: GSKStretchyHeaderView {
//    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
//    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
//    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
//    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
every UI component you need you must define here
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(**YourXibFileName**.nameOfClass, owner: self, options: nil)
        containerView.fixInView(self)
    }
    
    func config(your parameter) {
        // every thing you want
    }
}
```

after that you must use it in Your ViewController that contain a **TableView**:

```
var stretchyHeaderView: **YourHeaderFileName**!
    

func setupStretchyHeaderView() {
        stretchyHeaderView = **YourHeaderFileName**(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                             y: 0,
                                                             width: screenWidth,
                                                             height: SizeConstant.headerHeight.rawValue))
        stretchyHeaderView.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                        radius: SizeConstant.headerViewRadius.rawValue)
        tableView.addSubview(stretchyHeaderView)
        stretchyHeaderView.maximumContentHeight = SizeConstant.headerHeight.rawValue - navigationHeight
        stretchyHeaderView.config("your parameters that you needed")
        tableView.bringSubviewToFront(stretchyHeaderView)
        titleView.alpha = 0
//    Other setup
 }
```

and call this function **"setupStretchyHeaderView()"** on **viewDidLoad** life cycle

after that, you must work on **"scrollViewDidScroll"**

my need in code was like the below code:

```
extension **YourViewController** {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let yPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let value = ((Int(yPos) * -1) - Int(navigationHeight + 44))
        if (value < 1) {
            showNavbarTitle()
            showTitleView()
        }
        else {
            hideNavbarTitle()
            hideTitleView()
        }
    }
    
    func showNavbarTitle() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) { [self] in
            title = LocalizeString(key: Label.newReleases)
            loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func showTitleView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) { [self] in
            titleView.alpha = 1
            loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func hideNavbarTitle() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) { [self] in
            title = String()
            loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func hideTitleView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) { [self] in
            titleView.alpha = 0
            loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Not that the **nameOfClass** and **fixInView** methods are extensions